# Flatpickr: don't display the first week of the following month

Tags: flatpickr

I don't want to show the first week of the following month in the calendar. Can not see anything in docs https://flatpickr.js.org/options/

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit of CSS jiggery pokery gets the results I need.

Hide the empty additional week into next month:

```
        .nextMonthDay {
            &:nth-last-child(-n+7) {
                display: none;
            }
        }
```

Hide all into next month:

```
        .nextMonthDay {
            display: none;
        }
```

Hide all from previous month (uses `visibility` instead of `display` to preserve alignment beneath day names:

```
        .prevMonthDay {
            visibility: hidden;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Important to know is that hiding the dates by either the visibility or display property will break keyboard navigation.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35838090)